# Parsing Specific Input File Using Fscanf

Tags: c, parsing, scanf

i`ve been trying o use fscanf to read the an input file on my application.

This is the input file

```
3
Process#1 - 2Kb
3
exec 20

io 5

exec 50

Process#2 - 8Kb

1

exec 100

Process#3 - 8Kb

4

exec 50

io 50

exec 50

io 50
```

First of all i want to read the First "3", which i am having no problems doing so.

After that, i will need to read the information after the # (which is 1) and the number right after the "kb" string (which is 2).

Why is this fscanf failing to do so ?

```
fscanf(inputFile, "Process#%d - %dKb", &id, &mem );
```

How can i do it ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably because the newline left behind after the `3` is not being recognized by the `P` in `Process`.

This is why many people avoid `scanf()`; it is usually simpler to use `fgets()` or a related function (but *not* `gets()`!) and then use `sscanf()`.

---

#### Demo code

Notice the rigorous checking of the return from `scanf()`.  If you don't do that, you will not know when things have gone wrong.  Note that the check is for the correct number of conversions, too.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int i;
    int id;
    int mem;

    if (scanf("%d", &i) != 1)
        printf("oops!\n");
    /* With    space - reads past newline on first line */
    /* Without space - prints 'thank goodness!' */
    if (scanf(" Process#%d - %d", &id, &mem) != 2)
        printf("thank goodness!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So you are telling me to use fgets to read a whole line, and them, use the sscanf to parse the buffer i just filled using fgets ?

Comment: Based on your answer about the read missing the /n character, i fixed it using 

fscanf(entrada, "\nProcesso #%d - %dKb", &id, &mem ); 

Thanks, i will pick your answer in 5 minutes, once SO allows me

Comment: Yes.  It is easier to understand how that (`fgets()` plus `sscanf()`) works than to track how `fscanf()` works.  Alternatively, if you prefer, add a space before the `P` or `Process`; that will match arbitrary white space (including the newline).